# Compare growth rate of two functions. (Tricky)

Tags: algorithm

I need to compare the growth rate of the following functions:

f(n)=2^n and g(n)=n^log(n) (when n approaches positive infinity).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `n = 2^k`. We have:

```
2^n = 2^(2^k)
n^log(n) = (2^k)^log(2^k) = (2^k)^(k log 2)
         = 2^(k^2 log 2)
```

Now compare `2^k` to `k^2 log 2`. This is a basic comparison: `2^k` is bigger for all large enough `k`.

Comment: Wow this is an interesting approach. There is one thing I don't undestand though, how did this happen? (2^k)^(k log 2)= 2^(k^2 log 2)

Comment: @JohnDoe it's just the "power to a power" property: `(a^x)^y = a^(x*y)`. See here for example: http://www.icoachmath.com/math_dictionary/power_properties.html

Comment: What an incredible and simple solution! I have been struggling for days, thank you sir.

Comment: @John Doe Note that this approach is essentially similar to log(f) and log(g) comparison

Answer (score 1):

Taking `log` (base 2) for both the functions, we get `log(f(n)) = n` where `log(g(n)) = (log(n))^2`.

Now, `(log(n))^2 = o(n)` and `log` being a monotonically increasing function, we have

`g(n) = o(f(n))`, i.e., `f(n)` grows much faster for large values of `n`.

Here is another way to prove it more rigorously:

Let `L = lim{n->inf} g(n) / f(n) = lim{n->inf} n^(log(n))/2^n`.

Hence `log (L) = lim{n->inf} log^2(n) - n`

```
  ` = lim{n->inf} n*(log^2(n)/n) - 1)`

  ` = lim{n->inf} (n) * lim{n->inf} (log^2(n)/n) - 1)`

  ` = lim{n->inf} (n) * (0-1)`

  ` = lim{n->inf} (-n) = -inf`
```

`=> L = 2^(-inf) = 0`

According to the alternative definition of `o(n)` (small `o`, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation),

`L = lim{n->inf} g(n) / f(n) = 0`

`=> g(n) = o(f(n))`.

Here are the figures comparing `f(n)` and `g(n)` growth in original and in log scale:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it valid to compare the growth rate of the logarithms of two functions?

Comment: @JohnDoe why not? logarithms of  two functions are also (composite) functions. Basically what we should see here is that one function dominates the other's growth rate in log scale and log is monotonically increasing function, hence the first one will dominate the second one's growth in the original domain too.